# How to toggle off document.execCommand("superscript") back to normal text

Tags: javascript, html, editor, text-editor, execcommand

I am working on a custom text editor using a contenteditable div with basic formatting functionalities. I am using the command `document.execCommand("superscript", false, undefined);` to do superscript functionality, for example EXAMPLE<sup>TEST</sup>. what command can i use to turn this back to normal text.

Ps. clicking the initial command again does not work

I have tried `document.execCommand("superscript", false, undefined);` and also `document.execCommand("removeFormat", false, undefined);` both dont work to toggle it off.

Answer (score 0):

superscript is a toggle function, it will only work if text is not there

so to get text to normal we will have to use the command again but making sure text is there, so there is a way to check if text is there in selection by using `document.queryCommandState()` method

```
if (document.queryCommandState("superscript")) {
  document.execCommand("superscript", false, undefined);  
} else {  
  // there is no text
}
```

using removeFormat is not best option as it will remove all formatting

did that help ?